# SharePoint designer 2013: you don't have permission to open this website

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm a site owner and I'm able to open other sites from other site collections/accounts. Not sure what's the issue with mine. I have publishing activated.

Comment: check the permissions again, Are permissions broken for that specific site?

Answer (score 2):

Check if SharePoint Designer is enabled for this site.

(In SP2013) Navigate to the
`Site Settings` --> `Site Collection Administration` --> `SharePoint Designer Settings`
and check is **SharePoint designer enabled**. (`[SiteURL]/_layouts/15/SharePointDesignerSettings.aspx`)

Comment: form me this setting is not available in site settings