# is there any way to open a communication sharepoint site in the sharepoint designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, community-site

I tried to open a communication site in the SharePoint Designer but it shows me the following messages.
I have no problem with teams site. So, is there anything that I have to do to be able to open a communication site in the designer? or Designer can not open the communication site at all?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your community site do not have SharePoint designer enabled. Please refer to this old thread to check:

[SharePoint designer 2013: you don't have permission to open this website](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/194941/sharepoint-designer-2013-you-dont-have-permission-to-open-this-website)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. After following Mark L's answer, also open Internet Explorer before you try to connect. I can never connect if i haven't opened IE and logged into your tenant (any sharepoint website).